# Sticky Null Error Reference

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, null

I'm getting the null reference error at the "while" cycle's line... always... doesn't matter what I do.

```
if (Main.XCB.xArray!= null) {
    i = 0;
    while (i < Main.XCB.xArray.length){
```

Even if the xArray is null, it still drops the error... but why? It should stop it. Never had problem with doing this but now, everything ruined... I can't stop it even if I check it with a variable, nor if I prevent the function.

Any idea?

Comment: Post more code... Your Main class specifically -   Likely XCB is what's null

Comment: As @LondonDrugs_MediaServices says, you need to post more code. What you have written will never produce an error, except in the `if` statement. You'll get a better answer if you post code that someone can actually run to get the error. If that's too much to post, then still more is needed to understand the problem.